# how to install (bower) an angular directive to a Meteor application?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, bower

I have a Meteor application with an Angular frontend. I want to check for any unsaved data in forms before navigation. Found this Angular directive [angular-unsavedChanges](https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges) but it requires to be added with Bower. How can i use this in Meteor? **(Went through previous questions, and seperately downloaded and placed the directive in lib, still not woking)**
New bee to both Javascript and Angular, appreciate if you could be a little descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [basic usage instructions](https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges#basic-usage), you do not necessarily need to install this using Bower. You just need a hard copy of the files available in your project that can be referenced.

You should be able to set up this up with the following steps:

1. In your Meteor project, navigate to or create a directory named `public` in the root directory of the project.
2. Navigate to the `public` directory and create a new directory named `bower_components`.
3. Copy the files from the Github repo to this directory.

   - If using the command line, run the command `git clone git@github.com:facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges.git`.
   - If manually copying the files, create a new directory named `angular-unsavedChanges`, and save the files to this directory.
4. Inside the `<head></head>` tags that will be rendered on the page you want to use the code on (in your component, index file, head file, etc), add `<script src="/bower_components/angular-unsavedChanges/dist/unsavedChanges.js"></script>`.